# typescript not recognizing arrowfunction type in object

Tags: typescript, interface, arrow-functions, typing

Im currently working on a typesafe way of declaring an interface that declares how a function should return an object. This object should always contain the same functions. The interface is declared as follows:

```
import { DrawingMode } from '@/Pages/Planning/PlanningTypes'
import { Ref } from 'vue'

interface toggleable {
    reenable: () => void
    disable: () => void
}

interface createableByDraw {
    startDrawing: (drawingMode: DrawingMode) => void
    onCreated: (layer: L.Layer, drawingMode: DrawingMode) => void
}

export interface LeafletConnectionHookReturnObject
    extends toggleable,
        createableByDraw {}

export type LeafletConnectionHook = (
    currentMap: Ref<L.Map | undefined>
) => LeafletConnectionHookReturnObject
```

The Function is implemented like this:

```
export const useMappedXY: LeafletConnectionHook = (
    currentMap: Ref<L.Map | undefined>
) => {
    const onCreated = (layer: L.Layer) => {

    }


    const startDrawing = () => {
    }


    const reenable = (anyStringThatShouldNotBeAllowed: string) => {

    }

    const disable = () => {
    }

    return {
        reenable,
        disable,
        startDrawing,
        onCreated,
    }
}
```

As you can see, neither "onCreated" nor "startDrawing" implement the interface correctly. The function "reenable" even expects a completely different parameter than the interface suggests.
When i use my useMappedXY function in any other place, typescript expects the reenable function to implement the interface correctly. Why is that and what can i do to enforce the interface correctly?

If i rewrite my function like this:

```
export const useMappedXY: LeafletConnectionHook = (
    currentMap: Ref<L.Map | undefined>
) => {
    const onCreated = (layer: L.Layer) => {

    }


    const startDrawing = () => {
    }


    const reenable = (anyStringThatShouldNotBeAllowed: string) => {

    }

    const disable = () => {
    }

    const returnObject = {
        reenable,
        disable,
        startDrawing,
        onCreated,
    }

    return returnObject
}
```

then typescript does correctly infer that returnObject does not correctly implement the interface. But this seems easily exploitable and prone to error to me

Comment: I don't know why TS does not warn about the mismatch for the  `reenable` function. But as for the first two - there should be no error when the implementation ommits a parameter like this, because it just means the implementation ignores the parameter.

Comment: Works for me: https://tsplay.dev/N5AOBN Please provide a [mre].

Comment: To anyone stumbling across the same issue and wondering what i did to fix this. In short: i forgot that DrawingMode was a enum which used strings. So nothing wierd happened, everything worked as expected :D